# exibir o usuário que está logando PHP

Tags: php, pdo

Estou com um problema, que quando o usuário faz o login, correto, mostra uma *div* que apresenta a mensagem "Seja bem vindo" ( e gostaria que mostrasse o nome de usuário ) e a mesma não mostra, também gostaria que caso desse erro mostrasse uma *div* parecida só que com a mensagem "Preencha os campos corretamente".

Segue o código PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET('acao'])){
        if(!isset($_POST['logar'])){
        $acao = $_GET['acao'];
        if(acao=='negado'){
            echo '<strong>Erro!</strong> Você precisa estar logado';
        }
        }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['logar'])){
    //recuperar dados do form
    $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
    $senha = trim(strip_tags($_POST['senha']));

    //selecionar banco de dados
    $select = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE BINARY email=:email AND BINARY senha=:senha";
    try{
        $result = $conexao->prepare($select);
        $row=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $usuario= $row['nomeUsuario'];
        $result->bindParam(':email',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->bindParam(':senha',$senha, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $result->execute();
        $contar=$result->rowCount();
        if($contar>0){
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $senha = $_POST['senha'];
            $_SESSION['email'] =$email;
            $_SESSION['senha']= $senha;
            echo('
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
            <div id="mensagem">Seja bem vindo <?php echo $usuario; ?></div>
        </div>
            '); // MSG SUCESSO
            //header("Refresh:3, home.php");
        }else{
            echo('
            <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
                <div id="mensagem2">Preencha os campos corretamente</div>
            </div>
            ');//MSG ERRO
            header ("Refresh:3, index.php");
        }
    }catch(PDOException $error){
        echo "Erro: ". $error->getMessage();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: todos os dados da consulta estão retornando? Não é a causa mas é um erro if(acao=='negado'){ Tem que ser if($acao=='negado'){ faltou $

Comment: Isso, já tinha colocado rsrs é que copiei o código de outro pc que está offline. O login ele faz corretamente, minhas duas dúvidas são :
- Como mostrar o nome do usuário na div da mensagem "Seja bem vindo"
- Como mostrar a div de erro que não aparece quando da falha no login, seja usuário errado ou campo em branco.

Comment: escape o HTML, da seguinte forma if($contar>0) { ?> ... <div>acerto</div> <?php } else { ?> Erro <?php } ?>

Comment: Rapaz, seu codigo tem mais erro, fica dificil a gente ir direto no ponto que vc quer, EM if(isset($_GET('acao'])){ Falta um colchete [ Daria pra postar o codigo PHP correto?

Answer (score 1):

você tá colocando a variável dentro de aspas, separe elas, além de você não precisar abrir novamente a tag php:

Atual:

```
echo('
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
            <div id="mensagem">Seja bem vindo <?php echo $usuario; ?></div>
        </div>
            '); // MSG SUCESSO
```

Mude para:

```
echo('
        <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
            <div id="mensagem">Seja bem vindo ' . ' $usuario ' . '</div>
        </div>
            '); // MSG SUCESSO
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Você está usando PHP dentro de PHP, `<?php echo $usuario; ?>`

```
echo('
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
        <div id="mensagem">Seja bem vindo <?php echo $usuario; ?></div>
    </div>
        ');
```

o correto é

```
 echo("
    <div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-left:-145%;\">
        <div id=\"mensagem\">Seja bem vindo ".$usuario."</div>
    </div>
        ");
```

2 - esse seu style="margin-left:-145%;" pode ser o causador de não aparecer a div na tela. Veja

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-left:-145%;">
        <div id="mensagem">1 - Seja bem vindo Thiago Luiz Ferreira Tavares</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    
    <div class="row" style="margin-left:-145px;">
        <div id="mensagem">2 - Seja bem vindo Thiago Luiz Ferreira Tavares</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    
     <div class="row" style="margin-left:145px;">
        <div id="mensagem">3 -Seja bem vindo Thiago Luiz Ferreira Tavares</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: já tentei colocar desse modo e ele apenas me dá o retorno vazio. não sei se a sintaxe de puxar do banco de dados o $usuário está totalmente correta, sou meio leigo ainda com PDO rsrs

Comment: Mai eu perguntei no comentário lá em cima "todos os dados da consulta estão retornando?"  Deve ter mais erros então, vamos procurar

Comment: @ThiagoLuizFerreiraTavares  esse seu style="margin-left:-145%;" é o causador de não aparecer a div na tela. No codigo fonte ele aparece

Comment: o style="margin-left:-145%" não afetou no html na parte de sumir a div da tela, a primeira div do seja bem vindo aliás necessita dela para ficar alinhada. Já a div do Preencha corretamente elá não aparece com ou sem o style, a configuração não está impactando

Comment: Nesse caso para não ficar dando voltas a toa, é melhor você postar a sua aplicação em uso na integra. O código postado já está com erros que na sua aplicação não existem ...